# Segfault on JNI_CreateJavaVM

Tags: c++, linux, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I am trying for the first time to load a JVM from C++ via JNI but I can't seem to get it to work. I get a segfault when I call JNI_CreateJavaVM.

The code is pretty straight forward (copied mostly from an online example):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<jni.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    printf("Initializing JVM\n");
    JavaVM *jvm;
    JNIEnv *env;

    printf("Setting up args\n";
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.";
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;

    printf("Attempting to create JVM\n");
    jint rc = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);

    if(rc != JNI_OK) {
        printf("didn't work :(\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("JVM load succeeded!\n");
        jint ver = env->GetVersion();
        printf("Version: %i.%i\n", (ver>>16)&0x0f, ver&0x0f);

        printf("Cleaning up\n");
        delete options;
        jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
    }
    printf("Done\n");
}
```

My LD_LIBRARY_PATH contains /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/server which is the path containing a libjvm.so library. There are a few other libjvm.so libraries on my system, but most of them are for java 1.4. There is only one other jdk 1.6 libjvm.so and I tried using it as well with the same results.

I compile with:

```
g++ -g -c src/jniExpCppPart.cpp -I/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/include -I/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/include/linux -o obj/jniExpCppPart.o
g++ obj/jniExpCppPart.o -L/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm -o exe/jniExp
```

And when I run it within gdb, I get the first three print statements, followed by:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault
0x0000003249479e27 in strncmp () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0 0x0000003249479e27 in strncmp () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1 0x00002aaaaacd8c10 in Arguments::process_sun_java_launcher_properties(JavaVMInitArgs*) () from /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#2 0x00002aaaab2cfe7d in Thread::create_vm(JavaVMInitArgs*, bool*) () from /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#3 0x00002aaaaafcc800 in JNI_CreateJavaVM () from /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#4 0x0000000000400761 in main(argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe568) at src/jni/ExpCppPart.cpp:22
```

My guess is that the issue has more to do with how my environment is set up or how I built the executable rather than the code. Its been a few years since I really dealt with linking shared libraries, so its definitely possible that I messed something up.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

**Update**
I tried loading the library using dlopen instead (because I saw it in some Linux code that uses JNI). It didn't make difference, but I thought I'd include it here to see if it gives anyone a hint of what I may be doing wrong.

Once again I'm copying this by hand from a system that isn't connected to the internet, so there may be some typos.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<jni.h>
#include<dlfcn.h>

using namespace std;

//Create type for pointer to the JNI_CreateJavaVM function
typedef jint (*CreateJvmFuncPtr) (JavaVM**, void**, JavaVMInitArgs*);

//New method returns pointer to the JNI_CreateJavaVM function
CreateJvmFuncPtr findCreateJvm() {
    CreateJavaFuncPtr createJvm = NULL;

    void* jvmLib = dlopen("libjvm.so", RTLD_LAZY); //Get handle to jvm shared library
    char* error = dlerror(); //Check for errors on dlopen

    if(jvmLib = NULL || error != NULL) {
        printf("FailedToLoadJVM\n");
    }

    //Load pointer to the function within the shared library
    createJvm = (CreateJvmFuncPtr) dlsym(jvmLib, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");

    error = dlerror();
    if(error != NULL) {
        printf("Success\n");
    }

    return createJVM;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    printf("Initializing JVM\n");
    JavaVM *jvm;
    JNIEnv *env;

    printf("Setting up args\n";
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.";
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;

    printf("Attempting to create JVM\n");
    //Old code: jint rc = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
    //New code:
    CreateJvmFuncPtr createJVM = findCreateJvm();
    printf("findCreateJVM() returned 0x%x\n", createJVM);

    jint rc = createJVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
    //End new code

    if(rc != JNI_OK) {
        printf("didn't work :(\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("JVM load succeeded!\n");
        jint ver = env->GetVersion();
        printf("Version: %i.%i\n", (ver>>16)&0x0f, ver&0x0f);

        printf("Cleaning up\n");
        delete options;
        jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
    }
    printf("Done\n");
}
```

The output (similar to before) shows that everything is successful until it throws a segfault from within the JNI_CreateJavaVM method.

```
Initializing JVM
Setting up args
Attempting to create JVM
Success!
findCreateJVM() returned 0xc1e70780
Segmentation fault
```

So it seems that at the very least the program can find the library/function just fine. But something goes wrong when it's called. To me this indicates that it could either be just a simple API misunderstanding (I'm passing it something other than what I should be) or there's something weird with the shared library. Could this be caused perhaps if the shared library was compiled for an architecture/word size different than my program was compiled for? If so, how can I check the target architecture for both my program and the library?

Comment: with segfault i have a feeling the code you are using has a logic error. since a segfault is trying to access memory that is not there, like when you go over the bounds of an array. also makes sense you get the first three print statments since fails at the line `jint rc = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&&env, &vm_args);`

Comment: what command do you use to run the program? also compile with -Wall and -Werror

Comment: I run with just ./exe/jniExp
Or with gdb, gdb exe/jniExp followed by run

Comment: in that case i think it might be trying to read an expected argument that is not there. i mean it is hard to read with no comments so i could be wrong.

Comment: Here's the example code I was looking at with more comments: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/993067/Calling-Java-from-Cplusplus-with-JNI

Comment: hmm it was made for windows which might be a problem with low level calls being used

Comment: That could be the issue. I'll try to look for some Linux examples and see what differences there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is embarrassing...

I finally found out my problem and there's no way anyone on stack overflow could have fixed it because the code I posted in the question is actually correct, but it is not the same code as what I was running.

As I mentioned, I am running this code on a standalone system without internet access, so I had to copy the code by hand. In copying it, I corrected my mistake.

The code that is on my standalone system, includes the following lines:

```
JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.";
vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
vm_args.nOptions = 1;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;
```

Which you'll notice is not the same as the code I posted in the question. Because it is missing the line:

```
vm_args.options = options;
```

So of course it would cause a segfault because vm_args.options was never set to anything.

Answer (score 0):

The bug you're getting is on this line:

```
jint rc = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&&env, &vm_args);
```

You're asking for the address of the address of a pointer to the env; whereas if you look at the reference [example source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html):

```
#include <jni.h>       /* where everything is defined */
...
JavaVM *jvm;       /* denotes a Java VM */
JNIEnv *env;       //<!-- same as yours
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; /* JDK/JRE 6 VM initialization arguments */
JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=/usr/lib/java";
vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
vm_args.nOptions = 1;
vm_args.options = options;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;
/* load and initialize a Java VM, return a JNI interface
 * pointer in env */
JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args); // <!-- NOT the same!
delete options;
/* invoke the Main.test method using the JNI */
jclass cls = env->FindClass("Main");
jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "test", "(I)V");
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid, 100);
/* We are done. */
jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
```

You should change the code to read:

```
jint rc = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
```

Comment: Oops, that was actually a typo. The machine that I'm developing on doesn't have internet access, so I had to copy the code over by hand and I messed up. On the machine where I'm actually trying to run this, it only has the one '&'. I'll fix it in my post. You're absolutely right based on what I posted though.

Comment: If it's only a typo, then the code as is should work. It doesn't fail on either the mac or linux that I tried it on - both running java 8 latest, though.

Comment: Hmm... Well, my guess is that if it works on java 8, then it would work on java 6 (since the example I copied was made for java 6). I think it must be something about the way my environment is set up. Thank you so much for taking a look at it.

Comment: I just tested it on java 6 - looks to be the same as on your system and it worked correctly. The only suspicion I have is that the line `options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.";` isn't actually what you've got in the `.cpp` file of yours. There's a `strlen()` which would catch a null pointer, but if you used single quotes, and intentionally cast to a char *, and ignored the warning, I can trigger the same error as you.

Comment: Good thought, but unfortunately I used double quotes, so that's not it.