# Is it possible to call a JNIEXPORT function in Linux from c++?

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I am new to linux. (Windows users)
using the `.so file` (dll-like) library

I want to use a JNIEXPORT function in Centos7(linux).

example:

---

`test.so`

```cpp
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL JNI_foo(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jstring pathName)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(obj);

    // implements...

    return true;

}
```

---

`main.cpp` (in linux)

```cpp
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <jni.h>

typedef jboolean(JNICALL *Foo_TestFunc)(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jstring pathName);

int main()
{
    void* handle = dlopen("test.so", RTLD_NOW + RTLD_GLOBAL);

    if(handle)
    {
        *(void**)(&Foo_TestFunc) = dlsym(handle, "JNI_foo");

        JNIEnv jenv;
        jobject jobj;
        jstring jPath = jenv.NewStringUTF("/home/neohtux/Desktop/test.dat");

        jboolean isOk = Foo_TestFunc(&jenv, jobj, jPath);
    } 
}
```

Q1) Foo_TestFunc(`first`, `second`, path)
first parameter and in the second parameter
What should I convey? (on Linux)

Q2) `jenv.NewStringUTF("/home/neohtux/Desktop/test.dat");` Why am I getting segmentfalut in this function?

Comment: You might have forgotten to call `JNI_CreateJavaVM` at startup. Here's an example program: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/993067/Calling-Java-from-Cplusplus-with-JNI

Comment: Wouldn't this make far more sense with Java as the driver program? You can load the library from there and call `Foo`'s native methods as normal. The exact definition of Foo should be available from wherever you ripped that .so from. Worst case you can create your own Foo.

Comment: @Botje
I wanted to reuse a .so file made up of a JNIExport function in linux

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond
Thanks for the link you attached.
But I am getting segment fault error in `JNI_CreateJavaVM` .

similar problem :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37572993/segfault-on-jni-createjavavm

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo051 - once you have `JNIEnv` you can call `JNIEXPORT` method without any issues. Just make sure to initialise all the things you need inside your function before you call it.

Comment: Thanks for all replies.

Currently, I am not using JNI.

I'm making a separate one for cross-platform :)

Comment: Separate one of what?

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond 
I wanted to use the .so library file with the JNIEXport function in Linux, but

I'm just implementing it in native c++ (JNIExport function)

Comment: If neither the main application nor the plugin is written in Java then you can remove the JNI-specific parts.